# How to query / flatten from vertex ml results saved to bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, flatten, google-cloud-vertex-ai

This is driving me bonkers so any help greatly appreciated.

I am using Google's Vertex ML. I have exported a batch prediction to BigQuery.

The schema is I believe a record with repeat fields.

So I think it would like this in JSON:

```
[{"category":true,"score":.9999},{"category":false,"score",.05}]
```

I can not figure out how to either unnest or narrow a search where a category is true.

I need to have a flat select that has the correct category column and score value

```
123 | true | .9999
123 | false | .05
```

or a select with a where clause to only get true values

```
123 | .9999
```

The following unnests everything but it creates four rows joining both the true and false to both the scores.

```
SELECT
  row_id,
  classes,
  scores
FROM
  `database`
cross JOIN
  UNNEST(exported.classes) AS classes,
  UNNEST(exported.scores) AS scores
LIMIT
  10
```

creates rows like:

```
123 | true | .9999
123 | false | .9999
123 | true | .05
123 | false | .05
```

This does select the values I need but it's still a nested field...

```
select
row_id,
classes.classes,
classes.scores
from (
SELECT
  voter_id,
  ARRAY_CONCAT([predicted_results]) as the_results
FROM
  `data`
LIMIT
  10
),
unnest(the_results) as classes
```

creates rows like

```
123 | [true:.9999,false:.05]
```

Comment: Can I have a sample file or data so I can replicate your case?

Comment: @PoalaAstrid Yes! Here is what an exported JSON looks like  https://textbin.net/rpsvcch77u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
 primary_key, 
  predicted_supports.classes[SAFE_OFFSET(index)] as class,
  predicted_supports.scores[SAFE_OFFSET(index)] as score,
FROM `database`,
unnest(generate_array(0,array_length(predicted_supports.classes)-1)) as index
```

Here is the ouput:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! I would have never figured that out... Hopefully there are enough keywords here people searching can find this. if you have a coffee tip link or similar let me know i'll send a thank you!

Comment: I'm good, thank you! I'm just happy to contribute something to the community.

Comment: awesome very appreciated. it is definitely a bummer when people are dismissive/arrogant comments. like why participate. obviously not everyone has the knowledge and hence asking!